# Join (custom) query in Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to make a REST service using Spring Boot and Spring Data. I have written a query using `join` and have achieved the required o/p but I'm curious to know if that is a right way of doing it or I can do it with a better approach.

Here is the query using `@Query` annotation:

```
@Query("select b.bookId, b.bookName, a.authorId, a.authorName, b.language, "
            + "g.genreId, g.genreName,b.goodReadReviews from Book b, Author a, "
            + "Genre g where b.author=a.authorId and b.genre=g.genreId and "
            + "a.authorId=?1 and g.genreId=?2")
    List<Object[]> findByAuthorIdAndGenreId(int authorId, int genreId);
```

Comment: There is no issue in your approach as Spring Data JPA doesn't provide any out-of-box support JOINs.

Comment: Thank you @YogendraMishra. Can you please tell if Hibernate will provide a better approach for using join queries?